# Load mod_h264_streaming.dll in Windows Apache2

Tags: apache2, streaming, html5-video, h.264

Hi I am trying to stream video from static html5 pages serve by Windows Apache2. According to Apache guide on 
 http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2
this only for Linux, so I get the mod_h264_streaming.dll from 
 http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Internet-Information-Services-IIS7-Version2 but when I LoadModule h264_streaming_module modules/mod_h264_streaming.dll in httpd.conf it return

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Fo
undation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `h264_stre
aming_module' in file C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.
2/modules/mod_h264_streaming.dll: No error
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dll you downloaded is only for IIS not apache

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step
1- At first Download Visual Studio 2008 x64 SP1, be sure to install the Visual C++ 2008 x64 SP1 Redistributable Package
it can be downloaded from;

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=BA9257CA-337F-4B40-8C14-157CFDFFEE4E

2- Download Apache module mod_h264_streaming from ; https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/mod_h264_streaming/ in the below.Before download Please careful about your apache version.consider it.

3- Extrach files , copy "mod_h264_streaming.so"

3- If you are using Wamp server go the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\modules and drop(add,copy what ever you say) mod_h264_streaming file to the path. If you are not using wamp go to C:/Apache24/modules/ and add mod_h264_streaming.

4- Then Go to httpd.conf (in the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf path) , open with notepad++ find load modules line
just like ;

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so    // opened module
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so // closed module
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
```

When you find the lines add this ;

```
 LoadModule h264_streaming_module modules/mod_h264_streaming.so
```

save and quit. Finally restart the apache server. Module is ready to serve you.