# WAMP Server Streaming video MP4 start took to much time

Tags: php, apache, video, video-streaming, wamp

I am using WAMP server 2.4. I am streaming MP4 videos. Whenever i request video to stream it took around 3-4 mins to start streaming and once streaming is started it works fine.

I am unable to figure out why it takes to much time to start streaming.

I have tried following link as well but it didn't solve my issue.

[Load mod_h264_streaming.dll in Windows Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517374/load-mod-h264-streaming-dll-in-windows-apache2/22881490#22881490)

Please help

Comment: Are you sure it's not the client buffering the video before starting to play it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flash or HTML5 or else to playback the video?

It sounds like the browser/client is trying to get the full length file before playing it back. It could be due to the fact that your MP4 file is not properly formatted for the web (MOOV ATOM is at the end of the file and playback cannot begin without it). You can read there for more [info](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html).

I would suggest two things:

- try with a short 10 sec file and see if it plays rapidly
- try a software like handbrake (or MP4Box or ffmpeg if you are more advanced on file transcoding) to transcode your MP4 with the "web optimized" (aka "fast start") check box active.

Let us know if it works.

Comment: I am using HTML5. 
Will "ffmpeg" encode video.MP4 on server itself.
I created even 5 sec video from samsung S3 and place it on local server and still it takes around 3-4 mins. Size of video 5MB.

Comment: Ok it does not seem to be only an encoding issue more of a server side/network issue. Is there a proxy between your device and the local server? Are you trying to play the video on a mobile device? Is the device connected on Wifi with high speed? Can you try on different desktop browsers with a basic HTML5 video tag?

Comment: It gives same behavior on both desktop client browser and mobile device. Currently i am trying to fix it on localhost so expecting that if it works here then hopefully it will work correctly on mobile device. 
One thing that i have noticed is that it start buffering after 3-4 min and then buffering bar runs quickly.
internet speed is good. Same behavior with Wifi and Wired net. I have also tried it on different networks and different devices as well but same behavior

Comment: Can you try to play: `<video width="640" height="360" preload="auto" controls><source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"' /></video>`

Comment: Yes video at this link played immediately. I need exactly same behavior.
Please tell what configuration do i need.

Comment: Try to download the mp4 file http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4 and host it on your server. If it works, then you need to re-transcode your mp4 files. If it does not work then your server is badly tuned for video delivery. Try to read http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html for "MIME Types Rear Their Ugly Head". If it still does not work then you may consider re-install your WAMP Stack as it works on mine (2.4 as well).